# Phonegap - Sqlite query hangs UI thread in Android

Tags: cordova, android-sqlite, phonegap-plugins, sqlite

I have a code snippet where i'm trying to insert records into Sqlite DB that i'm getting from server. I'm using [PhoneGap Sqlite Plugin](https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-Android).
The data sometimes are of 2000 - 5000 in length so it takes around 10-15 sec to insert those data.

Basically, i'm showing a loading screen using the Sprite concept ( www.spritely.net/ ). The loading screen starts soon the ajax call is made, but the issue is that when the response comes and the code snippet runs to insert the records, the loading screen get hangs as well as the rest of the UI.

This is the code snippet,

```
    // Save the assignment
    this.saveAssignment = function(iAssignmentObj, iCallback) {
        try {
            this.db.transaction(function(iTx) {
                iTx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ASSIGNMENT (ID, SAMPLER_ID, ADDRESS_ID, ASSIGNMENT_DATE, LAST_UPDATE_TIME, STATUS) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                               [iAssignmentObj.Id, iAssignmentObj.SamplerId, iAssignmentObj.AddressId,
                                !!iAssignmentObj.AssignmentDate ? iAssignmentObj.AssignmentDate.getTime().toString(): '0',
                                !!iAssignmentObj.LastUpdateTime ? iAssignmentObj.LastUpdateTime.getTime().toString(): '0', iAssignmentObj.Status],
                    function() {
                        iCallback(true);
                    },
                    function() {
                        iCallback(false);
                    }
                );
            });
        }
        catch(iException) {
            console.log('local storage transaction failed for inserting assignment with id '+iAssignmentObj.Id);
            iCallback(false);
        }
    };
```

I call this function as like this

```
    // Process the response for Assignments
    this.processResponseForAssignments = function(iData, iIndex, iCallback) {

        var selfObj = this;
        if(iIndex>=iData.length) {
            iCallback();
        }
        else {

            selfObj.saveAssignment(iData[iIndex], function(iBoolean) {

                if(iBoolean) {
                    console.log('Assignment with Id : '+iData[iIndex].Id+' Inserted Successfully');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Unable to insert Assignment with Id : '+iData[iIndex].Id);
                }

                selfObj.processResponseForAssignments(iData, iIndex+1, iCallback);

            });

        }

    };
```

The matter that i'm concern is that this code works perfectly with iOs with the [PhoneGap Sqlite Plugin for iOs](https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-iOS), without hanging the UI, but it goes crazy with Android.

Please suggest what more do i need to make it work smoothly in Android.